# Once I accepted a postdoc offer with "A", is it ok to accept an invitation to present with group "B"?

Tags: etiquette, postdocs

Details are very important here:

I interviewed for postdoc positions at 2 labs (same university), and received offers from both.

I accepted the offer from lab "A", and when I declined the offer from "B", the PI told me that they were sorry about my decision, and that they would still like to invite me make a presentation for their lab. I thanked him for the invitation and agreed to make the presentation.

The two groups ("A" and "B") do not interact (they work on different fields), so this is essentially a matter of etiquette.

Is it ok if I make the aforementioned presentation now that I started my appointment with "A"? Should I inform the PI of "A" that I will go present with group "B"? Or should I just decline the invitation to present?

Comment: why wouldn't you give the presentation? Is there something hidden going on? why would you ask "A's" permission?  This is not at all clear to me..

Comment: @PsySp "Ask permission" might be a little strong. But it's courteous to at least check that your boss is OK with something you plan on doing during work time. Especially right at the start of a job when you're not sure what the expectations are.

Comment: Nothing to hide, not at all. But group "A"'s people might wonder why I still want to interact with the competence, and whether I'm interested in joining "B" (which is not the case).

Comment: @Elabore: By "the competence" do you mean "the competition"?

Comment: @ruakh yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 44):

Give the presentation.

There is no problem here (to be honest, I'm struggling to work out why you would think there is). Giving presentations is part of being an academic. Different groups can talk to each other. Different groups with close enough interested *should* talk to each other.

Comment: should I inform and/or ask for approval from my new group's PI?

Comment: I don't know. That will depend on your group. What would you do if today you received an invitation to give a talk at another university (within a day's return travel)? What did you do before in that situation?

Comment: "Should" is a word that should warn you of exactly why the OP has a question in their mind.  These two labs are obviously working on fields that, while different, are related enough that they are competing for resources (post-doc applicants at the very least), and are interested in the same topic (this applicant's prior work).  Competition can translate into politics and ill feelings.  Shouldn't, but far too often, it does.  So to categorically say "there is no problem here" is not a prudent position.  Better to err on the side of communicating more than expected.

Comment: Well, what makes me uncomfortable is the possibility that the new PI ("A") will not like that I interact with the competence. Although I'm not interested in joining "B", people at "A" might not like it... or maybe I'm just overthinking?

Comment: If your PI doesn't like you talking to to others, they have the problem, not you. It's possible you are working on something you can't share, but the acceptability of talking about what you've done before this position isn't affected by starting a new position.

Comment: @Elabore if you ever work in a group of someone who objects your giving a presentation to a group working on a different subject, run away. Fast. Presentations are an integral part of academia and while some people are indeed paranoid about others stealing their results, that's not relevant if the other group is working in a different field (and even when it is relevant, all you need to do is not give out all the details).

Comment: @terdon - "run away. Fast."...   that assumes that the person has the luxury of abandoning a post-doc position that has already been accepted.  It's not like opportunities like that grow on trees.  Far more practical, if working with such a group, is to communicate with the PI and see if there is any problem, and if there is, whether there might be content changes that would mitigate the problem.

Comment: Jessica, "they have a problem, not you" is not acceptable.  "They" are his new boss, whom he is going to have to relate to.  If he starts his new position by creating a problem for his boss, then the Elabore **will definitely** have a problem.  Not saying this is certain to be a problem, but assuming it could not possibly be, or that if it is, the OP should not worry about it... it is a completely untenable position.

Comment: Elabore, if your new PI has no problem with your presentation to the other group, but you communicate with him about it, then you will have lost nothing, but probably gained a little respect from your new boss for being a communicative and respectful sort of fellow.  If your new PI does have a problem, then communicating with him  will have saved you a load of future troubles and will have gained you a little more respect from your new boss, for the same reasons.  Bottom line, there is only upside to communicating and only potential misery for not doing it.

Comment: @JessicaB when you are working on a post-doctoral position, the Primary Investigator is your boss.  They are the ones that decided to hire you rather than someone else.  They have oversight over your research.  They can get rid of you, give you really good or really bad reviews and/or recommendations.  They are supposed to mentor you and help you gain research skills you need.  http://www.asbmb.org/asbmbtoday/asbmbtoday_article.aspx?id=9198.  If you think that is not authority, then I hope you are not a PI in charge of developing post-doctoral fellows, and I would never hire you as a post-doc.

Comment: @JessicaB - also, when did I ever suggest that "you should behave badly too"?  My suggestion, throughout, is for this post-doctoral fellow to communicate with his PI about the presentation, and see if there is a problem.  If there is not, great.  If there is, see how it could be resolved by editing the content of the presentation, possibly inviting the PI to attend, or even cancelling the presentation.  How is this bad behavior?

Comment: @JessicaB - Finally,  it is foolish to assume that the other position is still there.  If I was the PI in group B, I would never hire the OP if he leaves group A after a couple weeks.  Unreliability is unacceptable, and that is exactly what that kind of behavior would demonstrate, that the post-doctoral candidate could not resolve a simple communication issue, so he took off.  One of the worst qualities in a research candidate.

Comment: @JessicaB - Elabore, who made the decision to hire you in Group A?  Was it not mainly the PI?  If you have job reviews, who will conduct them?  Would it be the PI?  If you would like to extend your post-doc beyond its original term, who has to bless that?  The PI?  When you go look for a job after your post-doc, on job applications, who will you list as your supervisor during this post-doc?  The PI?

Comment: @JessicaB - you keep throwing around the word unprofessional, without having a clue why the PI in group A might have something to say about a presentation to group B. Maybe the PI in group A knows that group B is well known for stealing other people's work. Maybe the PI in group A knows that group B constantly poaches people from other groups. There is so much you, and I, and Elabore do not know that your assumptions are ridiculous. That is why it is best for Elabore to talk to his new boss first! One has to suspect that you have not dealt with the world of Academia, or at least not very well.

Answer (score 13):

Giving presentations is not a conflict; it is a normal part of academia. Interviewing with a group does not alter this.

The only question of conflict that arises here is if the time when you are to give the presentation is after the start date for the your work at PostDoc A since this means that you are unable to fulfil your normal duties. In this case you should inform your new PI of when you intend to give the presentation and it would be extremely unusual for your new PI to object, especially as it is at the same university.

Comment: I would argue that giving seminars is part of the normal duties of any academic. So I completely agree that it would be very unusual for the PI to object, though it's definitely courteous to let them know what you're doing.

Comment: Absolutely, I don't think that the PI would object, but they might think that I want to jump to the other group. That's my main concern.

Comment: Elabore, these two labs are obviously competing for resources - case in point, you.  So your concern that your new PI might be worried about losing you to the other group is a valid concern.  May turn out to be unfounded, but it is always best to check.  Talk to your new PI, heck, even invite him/her to come to the presentation and when there introduce them there as your boss.  This would show respect.  Can't lose by keeping things clear

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably *mention* it to A's PI, mainly to avoid surprises if you bump into them or they see the seminar advertised in the department.  They may well want to come to the seminar to hear more about that aspect of your work, or ask you to call meet up for a coffee while you're there.

Comment: "avoid surprises"... very well put.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the reality of Academia is that there is always politics in it, and you never know when that side of things is going to rear its ugly head.  So, I would talk to your PI in group "A" and let him know the situation.  If there are any political issues between groups "A" and "B", he/she can help you steer through them in a way that is acceptable to him/her.  It will communicate respect and will make your life easier and give a better impression of you to your new PI.

Even if this turns out to be a non-issue to your PI, they will see that you communicate and defer to their authority.  Goes a long way, in establishing trust in a new relationship, when you communicate at the least suspicion that something might be an issue.  Seeing as how you are posting here, you have that suspicion.  Even if turns out to be unfounded, the best way to deal with that suspicion is to, communicate.  When in doubt about any problem in relationships with your team, boss, friend, wife, a big part of the answer is always going to be communicate, communicate, communicate, and when you are done with that, communicate some more.

Comment: seems a healthy way